# Adding pcap file contents to Hash Table dynamically in lua

Tags: networking, lua, wireshark, network-traffic

I am trying to read .pcap file, and aggregate number of data packets for each client(client ip here is destination address). For example, if 5 data packets have been sent to xxx.ccc.vvv.bbb, i am outputting into a file in this format:

```
xxx.ccc.vvv.bbb 5
```

This is the program i have written below:

```
#!/usr/bin/lua

do
    numberofpkts = 0
    stat = {client1 = {numberofpkts = {}}}
    local file = io.open("luawrite","w")
    local function init_listener()
            local tap = Listener.new("wlan")
            local dest_addr = Field.new("wlan.da")
            local pkt_type = Field.new("wlan.fc.type")
            function tap.reset()
                    numberofpkts = 0;
            end

            function tap.packet(pinfo, tvb)
                    client = dest_addr()
                    client1 = tostring(client)
                    type = pkt_type()
                    if(tostring(type) == '2') then
                            stat.client1.numberofpkts = stat.client1.numberofpkts+1
                            file:write(tostring(client1),"\t", tostring(stat.client1.numberofpkts),"\n")
                    end
            end

    end
    init_listener()
end
```

Here, wlan.da gives the destination address. wlan.fc.type indicates that it is data packet(type = 2). I am running this using a tshark on wireless traffic.

I am getting an error:

```
tshark: Lua: on packet 3 Error During execution of Listener Packet Callback:
/root/statistics.lua:21: attempt to call field 'tostring' (a nil value)
tshark: Lua: on packet 12 Error During execution of Listener Packet Callback happened  2 times:
 /root/statistics.lua:21: attempt to call field 'tostring' (a nil value)
```

Please help me how i should solve this problem. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Seems that you're trying to make the stat table a dict of statistics; if so, make sure to initialize its members correctly (by the client, whatever its value is). Maybe this helps?

```
do
    stat = {}
    local file = io.open("luawrite","w")
    local function init_listener()
        local tap = Listener.new("wlan")
        local dest_addr = Field.new("wlan.da")
        local pkt_type = Field.new("wlan.fc.type")
        function tap.reset()
            local client = dest_addr()
            stat[client] = stat[client] or {numberofpkts = 0}
            stat[client].numberofpkts = 0
        end
        function tap.packet(pinfo, tvb)
            local client, type = dest_addr(), pkt_type()
            if(tostring(type) == '2') then
                stat[client] = stat[client] or {numberofpkts = 0}
                stat[client].numberofpkts = stat[client].numberofpkts + 1
                file:write(tostring(client),"\t", tostring(stat.client1.numberofpkts),"\n")
            end
        end
    end
    init_listener()
end
```